# How do I make eclipse JPA generate a one-to-one SQL table association?

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, jpa

I've been at this for hours, and I've tried using google and stackOverflow to see if anyone had my same problem before asking, but it seems this is unique to me.

I'm using glassfish server with eclipselink JPA. I've made a one-to-one relationship using mySQL workbench's EER diagram and after synchronizing my model to update my database, I've tried to make the corresponding entities using eclipse's "JPA entities from Tables" wizard.

However, in the Table Associations menu, eclipse identifies a 'many to one' relationship instead of a 'one to one'. The cardinality drop-box which is supposed to allow me to change this relationship is grayed out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I've been at it for hours too, and it keeps generating many-to-one relationships... :(

Comment: that question was asked a year ago. Anyway, yeah. It's a problem with the MYSQL workbench and not with Java. You'll have to re-write the tables and not use 'reverse-engineer' to actually do the table relationships. Pay close attention to the keys.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I was kind of desperate :) In the end I forced the relationships to be 1:1 by using the same primary key on the parent and the child table, and then JPA generated the entities as I wanted them. Thanks for answering, though!